# GridPane: RowConstraints percentHeight not working as expected

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, fxml

Having a GridPane with 2 rows and 2 columns, setting the row constraints to 50 percent height results in unwanted behaviour.

Code:

```
<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="..." stylesheets="@general.css" prefWidth="800" prefHeight="600">
    <top>
        <VBox>
            <!-- ... -->
        </VBox>
    </top>

    <bottom>
        <HBox>
            <!-- ... -->
        </HBox>
    </bottom>

    <center>
        <GridPane > 
            <children>

                <ScrollPane fx:id="tilePane" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
                    <content>
                    </content>
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="2" left="2" right="2" top="2" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                </ScrollPane>

                <TreeView fx:id="listPane" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <root>
                        <TreeItem value="Stages" />
                    </root>
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="2" left="2" right="2" top="2" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                </TreeView>

                <ScrollPane fx:id="mapPane" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.rowSpan="2">
                    <content>
                    </content>
                    <GridPane.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="2" left="2" right="2" top="2" />
                    </GridPane.margin>
                </ScrollPane>

            </children>

            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" percentWidth="25"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </columnConstraints>

            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" percentHeight="50" />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" percentHeight="50" />
            </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

*(mentioned attribute at the bottom)*

I expected that the two rows would share their available height at a 50% rate. They do this, but they also consume a lot more space than needed.

Picture of the result with, and without `percentHeight` specified:

[image: with percentHeight] [image: without percentHeight]

Do I understand `percentHeight` wrong, or is there another approach?

Comment: Perhaps related to: [RT-20099 Empty GridPane with percentWidth and percentHeight doesn't fit properly](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20099)

Comment: There are comments on the JavaFX CSS reference page saying that the percentage attribute does not apply to every element.  You could look at this post: [Percent Width for Table Column in JavaFX 2.x](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/percent_width_for_tablecolumn_in_javafx_2x_tablev.html])